# Why would I want to connect nginx to uWSGI?

Tags: nginx, mod-wsgi

I'm reading about running uWSGI behind nginx:
http://projects.unbit.it/uwsgi/wiki/RunOnNginx

Why wouldn't you just expose the uWSGI application directly -- why would you put it behind nginx?  (Is this even possible?  I'm a newb when it comes to this stuff.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

uWSGI is an application server, it is tuned and has options to run custom code in the safer possibile way. nginx is a webserver, and it is tuned and optimized for this kind of job (serving static files and proxying). You can run uWSGI as a webserver too but you will lose the amount of features of nginx (or whatever webserver you want to use) and its efficience in serving static files. There is a massive amount of other reasons (included security) but the main one is the different scope. so you need both. By the way, this is a normal paradigm (web server proxying to application server) for pratically all of the modern deployment solutions.